# How to save last state of list view in android (view should restore on opening the app)

Tags: android, listview

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);
 //  dont know how to use this 
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
    // same for this one
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving Android Activity state using Save Instance State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-android-activity-state-using-save-instance-state)

Comment: i want to actually know how to do it for list views

Comment: What difference does it make ? The thing you need to understand here is `Bundle` you can only save data which `Bundle` allow . So read about `Bundle` first . And then figure out what data you need to save .